# Show window only for a specifc time and then close it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, window

I want to close my window after a specifc time, but it depends on a property. If this is true it should be closed after 6seconds, otherwise after 3 seconds. I want to have almost everything in xaml done. I'm not satisfied with c# code.

Here what I have tried so far:

my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="embedUserc.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:embedUserc="clr-namespace:embedUserc">
<Window.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="False" >
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:6" FillBehavior="Stop"  >
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseBehavior" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Close">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="True" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="True" >
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:4" FillBehavior="Stop"  >
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseBehavior" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Close" >
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="True" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <embedUserc:WindowCloseBehavior x:Name="CloseBehavior"/>
</Grid>
```

My c# code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace embedUserc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class WindowCloseBehavior : FrameworkElement
    {
        public static void SetClose(DependencyObject target, bool value)
        {
            target.SetValue(CloseProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Close",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(WindowCloseBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnClose));

        private static void OnClose(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
            {
                Window window = GetWindow(sender);
                if (window != null)
                    window.Close();
            }
        }

        private static Window GetWindow(DependencyObject sender)
        {
            Window window = null;
            if (sender is Window)
                window = (Window)sender;
            return window ?? (Window.GetWindow(sender));
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public bool IsSomething { get { return true; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now, here is the working xaml with the same c# code:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style x:Key="CloseStyle">
     <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="False" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:6" FillBehavior="Stop"  >
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Close" >
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="True" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard> 
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="True" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:4" FillBehavior="Stop"  >
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Close" >
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="True" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```